# Spring Security with webgate

Tags: spring-security

I am developing a spring MVC application.I am implementing spring security with webgate. I am following [this](http://blog.sbeynon.net/2011/12/spring-security-with-sso-headers.html) article. I am getting the following error when i implement same as it is in blog.

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method not found: No constructor found that can take a single argument of type class org.springframework.security.web.firewall.RequestWrapper

[image]

My buildDetails(-) code is like this

```
public Object buildDetails(Object context)
 {
     System.out.println("HeaderAuthenticationDetails:buildDetails::: "+context);

    Object result = super.buildDetails(context);  //getting error in super class
        List<GrantedAuthority> userGas = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        if (result instanceof MutableGrantedAuthoritiesContainer) {
          Collection<String> userRoles = getUserRoles(context, allRoles);
          userGas = (List<GrantedAuthority>) grantedAuthoritiesMapper.getGrantedAuthorities(userRoles);
          ((MutableGrantedAuthoritiesContainer) result).setGrantedAuthorities(userGas);
        }
        return result;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to resolve the issue by modifying the buildDetails(-) as below

```
public Object buildDetails(Object context)
 {       
     List<GrantedAuthority> userGas = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
     MutableGrantedAuthoritiesContainer container=new PreAuthenticatedGrantedAuthoritiesAuthenticationDetails(context);
     Collection<String> userRoles = getUserRoles(context, allRoles);
     userGas = (List<GrantedAuthority>) grantedAuthoritiesMapper.getGrantedAuthorities(userRoles);
      container.setGrantedAuthorities(userGas);
        return container;
 }
```

And added an "anonymous" role when no roles exists in request header in my getUserRoles(-,-) method